# Why solr delete document when adding documents with different ids?

Tags: solr, solrj

While I'm adding 30323 documents into my solr core which already have one million documents, only part of the 30323 can be added. Nearly 3000 documents can not be added. I found that they are deleted by solr in deleteDocs. I've checked to make sure there's no duplicate id.
The more confusing thing I found is that the number of documents solr delete is not definite, sometime 2800, while next time 3200..
Can someone give me any advise on this matter?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you any error or stacktrace ?

Comment: no error, I use tomcat as the container, and the log shows that all 30323 has been added to solr, but the deleteDocs num in Core Admin shows nearly 3000 documents is deleted.

Comment: While adding document, seeing docs being deleted can be seen only when there are duplicate docs being added. While adding doc, If unique field value is same as existing one then existing document is deleted and new one is added .

Comment: I got your point, and the first time I thought the same way. But sth I forget to mention is that the first time I add these docs to solr, it's ok, all 30323 docs can be added, while this time as the requirement, I need to reload these docs. And I delete all 30323 docs before reload them, then I can't get all of them, a part of them is missing, I wonder that is there anything related to cache?